# Traducción de "hacer(le) caso"

Tags: definiciones, expresiones

Yo he vivido en El Salvador por unos años y frecuentemente he escuchado la expresión *hacer(le) caso*. No estoy seguro si es una expresión local o si otros lugares la usan también.

Ejemplos:

> Le dije al niño que obedeciera, pero nunca me hizo caso.
>
> Mi hijo no me hace caso.

Sospecho que significa algo como cuando alguien no hace lo que quiero, pero quisiera una explicación completa de esta expresión y como usarla.

Comment: "Hacerle caso a alguien" es español estándar. Por tanto, es común y comprensible en cualquier país de habla hispana.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La frase "hacer caso a alguien" tiene dos definiciónes principales según la [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7pG16he):

> 1. Prestarle la atención que merece
> 2. Obedecer, ser dócil

Esta frase se traduce al inglés como "to pay attention" o a veces como "to listen to".